# Why do I get "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed a simple Web API and deployed it on an Azure server along with a SQL Server database. The database and the Web API are hosted on the same server. I can connect to the database from my development machine. If I run the Web API in Visual Studio 2017, everything works fine, I can call all Web methods and I get the proper expected response.
Now, that I deployed the Web API on the server and run it under IIS, if I make a Web API call using Postman I get this error message after about 30 seconds of wait time:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

I know this error has been discussed here many times, but none of the suggestions made help solve my problem. The hosting Azure VM is a 64-bit Windows Server 2016.

In the connection string used by my Web API I had the data source set to the computer's name, its internal Ip address, the "localhost" keyword or the "127.0.0.1" back-loop IP address, but I get the same error listed above in each of those situations. SQL Server Management Studio (running locally on the same server that hosts the database and my Web API) is able to connect to the database if I use either of the three data sources: localhost, internal IP address or computer name.

In the situation in which it works, when I run the Web API in Visual Studio, the data source in the connection string is set to the external Ip address of the Azure Server. That would be the only difference, as far as the data source is concerned.

I need to mention that I have a couple of web methods that do not require database access. These work fine and return the expected result.

Are there other specific settings that I would need to do in IIS to allow this to happen?

TIA,
Eddie

Comment: That error is the basic "could not connect to the database" error.  When running under VS, you are probably running "as you".  When running under IIS, you may be running under a different IIDentity.  Aka, the user that the process is running under.  you should post your (scrubbed for real values) connection string in your question.

Comment: @granadaCoder Thanks for your suggestion. I meant to post the connection string, but it wouldn't have helped you at all. My connection string was correct, except it was in the wrong file.

Comment: "connection string was correct, except it was in the wrong file" . Technically, that's an oxymoron....but I get ya!  (haha) Glad you figured it out.   Reminds of this time a dba said "I had the path right, but i misspelled one of the foldernames".  #oxymoron

Comment: I meant that I would have given you the connection string from the wrong file. You would have looked at it and wouldn't have seen any issues with it because it was the correct string. Just a brain fart on my part, but thanks for taking the time to read the question and making an effort to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured what the problem was. My Web API was developed in ASP.Net Core and as such, it produces its own executable. That is looking for a config file that is named TheNameOfTheApplication.exe.config.

Due to a temporary lapse of reason, I was modifying the connection string in the "app.config" file and left the one in the "TheNameOfTheApplication.exe.config" file with the external IP address that was not correct.